# Geocoding client not sending requests to geocoding api

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, nodes, geocoding

I am trying to use [google-maps-services javascript library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) from Node.js on Firebase Cloud Function. I wish to obtain (lat, lng) from street address. For testing purpose I am running a schedulable firebase function and making a call to library functions from there. However, only my error path is getting executed. Below are the environmental details and code snippet that I am using

#### Environment details

- Platform: firebase cloud functions on Node.js v8
- Geocoding API version: 2.0.2

#### Steps to reproduce

Running an async function which is requesting (lat, lng) from geocoding api. The function body (inside of index.js) is below

```
async function getDriverLocationNearAddress(streetAddress){
const geocodingClient = new Client({});
let params = {
        address: streetAddress,
        components: 'country:US',
        key: API_KEY_GEOCODING
    }; 
    console.log('retrieving lat, lng for ' + streetAddress);
    return geocodingClient.geocode(params)
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('status: ' + response.data.status);
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
        return response;
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('error retrieving geocoded results');
    });
}
```

The following initialization has been performed

```
API_KEY_GEOCODING='*******************************'; // key not shown
const Client = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js").Client;
```

I am running this function periodically using scheduler API every 1 min

```
exports.scheduledUpdateDriverLocations = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun( (context) => {
    return getDriverLocationNearAddress('1042 Middlefield Rd, Redwood City, CA');
});
```

The console logs show that my `getDriverLocationsNearAddress` keeps hitting the catch statement without printing any logs in the `then` section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFNuR.png)

However if I try to access the geocoding API using browser, it is working
My google cloud api console shows that I did not receive any api requests, except the one sent using the browser. In the image below, I only see one request, although I sent requests every minute, a few minutes after the indicated event.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idlrr.png)

This is the error log. It seems like my request is badly formed, but not sure why that is the case

```
{ Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  config: 
   { url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
     method: 'get',
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'google-maps-services-node-2.0.2' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     paramsSerializer: [Function],
     timeout: 10000,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     httpsAgent: 
      HttpsAgent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: {},
        freeSockets: [Object],
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        createSocketCount: 52,
        createSocketCountLastCheck: 0,
        createSocketErrorCount: 0,
        createSocketErrorCountLastCheck: 0,
        closeSocketCount: 51,
        closeSocketCountLastCheck: 0,
        errorSocketCount: 0,
        errorSocketCountLastCheck: 0,
        requestCount: 52,
        requestCountLastCheck: 0,
        timeoutSocketCount: 51,
        timeoutSocketCountLastCheck: 0,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object],
        [Symbol(agentkeepalive#currentId)]: 52 },
     address: '1044 Middlefield Rd, Redwood City, CA',
     components: 'country:US',
     key: '************************************',
     data: undefined },
  request: 
   ClientRequest {
     domain: 
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [Array] },
     _events: 
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Array],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'maps.googleapis.com',
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 178,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        _idleTimeout: 15000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 3119505,
        _destroyed: false,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: -1,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 4567,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 0,
        [Symbol(agentkeepalive#socketName)]: 'sock[51#maps.googleapis.com:443:::::::::]',
        [Symbol(agentkeepalive#socketRequestCount)]: 1,
        [Symbol(agentkeepalive#socketRequestFinishedCount)]: 1 },
     connection: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername:
```

Comment: Is your key restricted?  I suspect the client request is using the webservice, in which case a key restricted for the Javascript API would not work.  Try creating a web service key and using that.

Comment: (or a unrestricted key, for a quick test)

Comment: I tried as you suggested and set the key to be unrestricted - removed both application and API restrictions. Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running the minimal example on elevation API from the [google-map-services library for node.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js), I was able to figure out that the problem concerned with how to supply parameters to the `geocode` function.

I changed the node.js code as follows

Before: I didn't supply the field name `params`

```
async function getDriverLocationNearAddress(streetAddress){
const geocodingClient = new Client({});
let params = {
        address: streetAddress,
        components: 'country:US',
        key: API_KEY_GEOCODING
    }; 
    console.log('retrieving lat, lng for ' + streetAddress);
    return geocodingClient.geocode(params)
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('status: ' + response.data.status);
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
        return response;
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('error retrieving geocoded results');
    });
}
```

After:

```
async function getDriverLocationNearAddress(streetAddress){
const geocodingClient = new Client({});
let params = {
        address: streetAddress,
        components: 'country:US',
        key: API_KEY_GEOCODING
    }; 

    console.log('retrieving lat, lng for ' + streetAddress);
    geocodingClient.geocode({
        params:params
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('status: ' + response.data.status);
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
        return response;
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('error retrieving geocoded results');
    });
}
```

Comment: btw, I am running with unrestricted api key

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, what I am seeing is that you cannot call the API from your webserver (cross origin request). Find your webserver name (e.g. localhost:8080) and add that as an authorized javascript origin. Information on the exact steps that have to be followed you can find [here](https://support.google.com/gsuitemigrate/answer/9222992?hl=en).

This behaviour is usually the case when you can access using a browser, but you cannot access the API from within (javascript) code. I would also recommend printing the exact error instead of a logging statement, or just print both from within your catch block. Something like this:

```
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log('Error retrieving geocoded results: ' + error);
});
```